# How to Bind Port In java Class

Tags: java, swing, sockets, serversocket

I am using Swing and now i want to Allocate one Special port for the Java class which is running in my swing. so how do i bind that port so every time when user run that so there wont be creating new object it will show message that process is already running!! I need to Bind that port to the Process how to do it?

```
Socket s = new Socket();
s.bind(new InetSocketAddress(9000));
```

i have bind this address but how to bind it in current class object.?

Comment: Please share what have you done already? Please share some code part to make it more clear.

Comment: static? see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: Your question still doesn't make any sense. What exactly are you trying to do and what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: @Philipp I want to Bind that process when that class is running. into the that port and if that user again start that class. then that should be not run. instead of that i want to show that message that process is already running. u get it now??

Comment: That's what already happens. You can't bind twice to the same port in two different processes, at least not without special arrangements. So what's your question?

Comment: Question is how to check that 9000 port is running some process. not from out put but from code.

Comment: Just bind to it. If it's already bound you get a BindException. Is that what you want? If it isn't, you're going to have to try a lot harder to ask a clear and answerable question.

Comment: ya i got that exception that is right. but now if person runs again that code there should be message that process is already running. and btw i need to check it by code not with exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use static variable - this object will be created only once

```
private static Socket s = new Socket();

static {
    try {
        s.bind(new InetSocketAddress(9000));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: That is what i have already done dude. and more of it i want to check that weather in that port process is running or not.

Comment: you can check it via telnet, simply connecting to localhost:9000 (btw, you do not wrote anything about static objects)

Comment: ya but if i do that what will be out put i mean what that class will run again?

Comment: you can check that port in some swing onCreate() method and if it is already in use - print out that message

Comment: ya that is right but if i want to check it. means i want to check that  port is running on any process or not. so how to check it?

Comment: 1. you can get socket address from your socket and check null + compare it with your address
2. you can bind it again and handle IOException, if it thow - print out message

Comment: Well can u give reference example??

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
        Socket s = new Socket();
        try {
            s.bind(new InetSocketAddress(9999));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); //here all be ok
        }
        try {
            s.bind(new InetSocketAddress(9999));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage()); // here we get SocketException : already bound
        }
    }

Comment: okey i got it let me check :)

Comment: is this true   try {
            s.bind(new InetSocketAddress(9000));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            
            e.printStackTrace();
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            if (e.getMessage().equals("Address already in use")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Process is already Running");
                System.exit(0);
                return;
            }

Comment: +1 for your ans dude its almost what i want. :)